# std::algorithms friendly way to iterate over `std::vector<std::vector<something>>`

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

A common pattern in my current project is something like:

```
for(auto& row: matrix)
{
    for(auto& col: row)
    {
        //insert simple operation here:
        //return when condition is true
        //increase counter when condition is true
        //etc
    }
}
```

As you can see the conditions would perfectly fit into some `std::algorithm`, but I don't really know how to iterate over this structure. Because of this most of the simple things, like counting the elements for which a condition is true,  have several lines instead of one line.

Can you please suggest me a way of defining a matrix like data structure to make it friendly to use with `std::algorithms`?

Comment: Write a 2D matrix class with access to elements via begin() and end() iterators. Internally, you can use `vector<something>`.

Comment: This will make it difficult to iterate over a row. Can you please extend this?

Comment: @Felics You could provide `begin_row(i)`/`end_row(i)` and `begin_column(i)`/`end_column(i)` iterators as well. Standard library algorithms accept begin/end pairs instead of containers, so this allows you the flexibility to use these algorithms on the whole matrix, a single column, or a single row.

Comment: Another option is to use a proxy row type which references the data corresponding to a particular row.

Comment: Check out Boost.Iterator, which is a library to help you write STL-style iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost` has ways to merge multiple ranges into one range.

If you cannot use `boost`, you can write something like this:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct Range {
  Iterator b_, e_;
  Range( Iterator b, Iterator e ):b_(b), e_(e) {}
  Iterator begin() const { return b_; }
  Iterator end() const { return e_; }
  bool empty() const { return begin() == end(); }
  template<class C>
  static auto adl_begin(C&& c) {
    using std::begin;
    return begin( std::forward<C>(c) );
  }
  template<class C>
  static auto adl_end(C&& c) {
    using std::end;
    return end( std::forward<C>(c) );
  }
  template<class C>
  explicit Range(C&& c):
    Range(adl_begin(std::forward<C>(c)), adl_end(std::forward<C>(c)))
  {}
  Range():b_(), e_() {}; // Range of pointers should be null null just in case
  Range( Range const& ) = default;
  Range( Range && ) = default;
  ~Range() = default;
  Range& operator=(Range const&)=default;
  Range& operator=(Range &&)=default;

  friend bool operator==( Range const& lhs, Range const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.b_ == rhs.b_ && lhs.e_ == rhs.e_;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( Range const& lhs, Range const& rhs ) {
    return !( lhs == rhs );
  }
};
```

the above is a pretty simple `Range` template that lets you store pairs of iterators in a bundle that can be iterated over and thought about as a single unit.  `boost` has one of those as well, probably better written.

Next, an iterator over two nested ranges:

```
template<class Outer, class Inner>
struct bi_iterator:std::iterator<
  std::forward_iterator_tag,
  typename std::iterator_traits<Inner>::value_type
  // in theory add more, but I won't bother
> {
  using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<Inner>::value_type;
  Range<Outer> outer;
  Range<Inner> inner;
  explicit bi_iterator( Range<Outer> out ):outer(out), inner(advance())
  {}
  friend bool operator==( bi_iterator const& lhs, bi_iterator const& rhs ) {
    if (lhs.outer != rhs.outer) return false;
    if (lhs.outer.empty()) return true;
    return lhs.inner == rhs.inner;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( bi_iterator const& lhs, bi_iterator const& rhs ) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
private:
  Range<Inner> advance() {
    if (outer.empty()) return;
    inner = Range<Inner>( *outer.begin() );
    rectify();
    return inner;
  }
  void rectify() {
    if (!inner.empty()) return;
    if (outer.empty()) return;
    outer = {std::next(outer.begin()), outer.end()};
    inner = advance();
  }
public:
  value_type& operator*() { return *inner.begin(); }
  bi_iterator operator++(int) {
    bi_iterator retval = *this;
    ++(*this);
    return retval;
  }
  bi_iterator& operator++() {
    inner = { std::next(inner.begin()), inner.end() };
    rectify();
    return *this;
  };
};
template<class Outer, class Inner>
Range<bi_iterator<Outer,Inner>> bi_range_helper( Range<Outer> out ) {
  return { bi_iterator<Outer,Inner>(out), bi_iterator<Outer,Inner>({out.end(), out.end()}) };
}
template<class Container>
auto bi_range( Container&& c ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto b = begin(c);
  auto e = end(c);
  using Outer = decltype(b);
  using Inner = typename std::decay<decltype(begin(*b))>::type;
  return bi_range_helper<Outer,Inner>( {b,e} );
}
```

Then:

```
auto bi = bi_range( matrix );
for( auto&& element: bi ) { /* stuff */ }
```

should iterate over the 2nd dimension of `matrix`, and

```
using std::begin; using std::end;
auto b = begin(bi);
auto e = end(bi);
```

should be some `<algorithms>` compatible forward iterators into the elements in the 2nd dimension of matrix.

Note that there may be some errors above, I wrote it without any tests or even compiling it.

(Aside: always use `std::begin` and `std::end` in ADL-compatible contexts, hence the `using std::begin` clauses).

If you get the above to work, a fun project: make `nary_iterator` that builds recursive `bi_iterator` types to chain any amount of depth.  For an advanced problem, do it without chaining `bi_iterator`.

Note that my `bi_iterator` is going to be inferior to the boost version (I forget what it is called) in many ways, as I just whipped it out, and `boost` undergoes review.